# get_PropertyName()/set_PropertyName() vs PropertyName?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, propertyinfo

I'm using reflection on the assembly of a public API I am working with along with `System.CodeDOM` to generate some code that will extract information through the API.

In part of my auto-generated code I am referencing the values of a number of properties of types in the API assembly. However, I keep ending up with references to properties that don't actualy exist in my generated code. I used `Type.GetProperties()` which from what I understand should only return public properties.

I looked into it further and found that when I had a missing property, say called `SampleProperty` there were instead two methods in the class called `get_SampleProperty` and `set_SampleProperty` but no actual `SampleProperty` property.

What's going on here? Why does intellisense treat these methods as separate methods, but when when returned through reflection they show up as a property?

Comment: I think I would need a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) to be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

> I used PropertyInfo.GetProperties() which from what I understand should only return public properties.

That might be your first hang-up, the PropertyInfo class doesn't have a GetProperties method.  The Type class does.  Your question otherwise indicates that you are actually using Type.GetMethods().  Yes, that returns the get_Blah and set_Blah property accessor methods for a property.  Under the hood, properties are actually implemented as methods.

Use Type.GetProperties() to reflect properties.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo I was using Type.GetProperties()